# 'DecisionTreeClassifier' object has no attribute 'export_graphviz'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm using python sklearn RandomForestClassifier and try to export decisiontrees.

The basic code is as following:

```
from sklearn import tree

with open(dot_file_name, 'w') as my_file:
    tree.export_graphviz(tree1, out_file = my_file,feature_names = feature_names)
```

After run the python script, following error show up:
Attribute error: 'DecisionTreeClassifier' object has no attribute 'export_graphviz'

I'm using python 2.7. Is it because of the version of python? Do I have to use python 3.0?

Comment: Did you make sure you have all the prerequisites installed?

Comment: you may want to show more of your code?

Answer (score 5):

That's because you used somewhere `tree` name as name for `DecisionTreeClassifier`. Use another name there.